# Convert binary image (monochorme) to sampling image

Tags: android, image-processing, binary, sampling

I have got some problem about converting image to sampling image like this picture below.
first I managed to convert the image to binary image/monochrome image from live camera using this code

```
 protected Bitmap processFrame(byte[] data) {
        //int frameSize = getFrameWidth() * getFrameHeight();
        int[] rgba = mRGBA;

              for (int i = 0; i < getFrameHeight(); i=i+1){
                for (int j = 0; j < getFrameWidth(); j=j+1) {
                    int index = i * getFrameWidth() + j;
                    int y = (0xff & ((int) data[index]));
                    if(y>128)y=0;
                    else y=0xff;
                    rgba[i * getFrameWidth() + j] = 0xff000000 + (y << 16) + (y << 8) + y;
                }
            }  

        mBitmap.setPixels(rgba, 0/* offset */, getFrameWidth() /* stride */, 0, 0, getFrameWidth(), getFrameHeight());
        return mBitmap;

    }
```

1. But the next step I want to display these binary image become sampling image like this picture below

where I can add the code for displaying sampling image? like this site: [http://cse.ust.hk/learning_objects/imagerep.html](http://www.cse.ust.hk/learning_objects/imagerep.html)

Comment: According to the own link you included, the sampling is `height x width`. So you just need to display the height and the width, how is that a problem ?

Comment: the problem is I want to convert image source to sampling image. I try to change the display image from the value of sampling rate (horizontal rate and vertical rate). so I can display the image become like pixelize image

Comment: I can barely understand what you write. Maybe you want to represent pixels in a larger manner, or maybe you want to downscale your image and show it in a larger resolution ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes i just want to downscale these image frames and show it in a larger resolution. eemm like matrix picture (pixelize). have you got any idea to modification those source code?

Comment: There are many ways to downscale an image, one of the easiest is by applying a nearest neighbor interpolation. Then to show in a larger resolution you upscale by nearest neighbor interpolation.